# Constraint Layout shifted down over screen edge

Tags: android

I've been using Constraint Layouts for a while but today I faced a strange problem, all my layouts that contain constraint layouts are shifted down over the lower screen edge although the width and height of the parent constraint layout are (match-parent), the result is below

[image]

and here's is the XML code for the layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    tools:context=".Setup_SettingsActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/setup_pharmacy_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/setup_pharmacy_name" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="@string/setup_welcome"
        android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/setup_pharmacy_address"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/setup_pharmacy_name">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/setup_pharmacy_address"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/setup_save_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="@string/setup_save_btn_text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/setup_has_delivery_switch" />

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/setup_has_delivery_switch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="@string/setup_has_delivery_switch_text"
        android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default"
        android:textOff="@string/setup_delivery_switch_off"
        android:textOn="@string/setup_delivery_switch_on"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/divider" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.476"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/setup_pharmacy_address"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/position_btn" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="42dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/setup_pharmacy_address"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/position_done" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:text="@string/setup_record_position_text"

        android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageButton"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/setup_pharmacy_address" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:background="@color/divider"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageButton" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@color/divider"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/setup_has_delivery_switch" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

what might be the cause of this problem?

Comment: You need to constraint your last view from bottom and best practise is to add a scrollview as all views might not able to visible on small screen size

Comment: Check the layout compatibility in ide with multiple screen sizes, after that put margins according, or put inside scroll view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Your layout got pushed down because you are using way too large margins - you are using `constraintLayout` but you are also using large fixed size for your margins (`android:layout_marginTop="60dp"` for example) and because different phones got different screen size, when you are using a fixed size on your view you are making your layout less responsive(small margins are ok but the problem starts with the large margins).
- If you want to place some view somewhere at your screen I would recommend using [guielines](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/guidelines.html) and constraint your views into the guideline rather then give your view a lot of margins.

You can simply use [chains](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/create_chains.html) to achieve your desired layout.

**Here is an example of the layout that you want to achieve using cnostraintLayout and chains:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/setup_pharmacy_name"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/setup_pharmacy_address"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="setup_pharmacy_name" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="setup_welcome"
    android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/setup_pharmacy_name"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/setup_pharmacy_address"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView6"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/setup_pharmacy_name">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="setup_pharmacy_address"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/setup_save_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
    android:text="setup_save_btn_text"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/divider2" />

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/setup_has_delivery_switch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="setup_has_delivery_switch_text"
    android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default"
    android:textOff="setup_delivery_switch_off"
    android:textOn="setup_delivery_switch_on"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/divider2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/divider" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView2"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView6"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView6"
    app:srcCompat="position_btn" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="42dp"
    android:layout_height="38dp"
    android:src="@drawable/new_question"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView6" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="setup_record_position_text"

    android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/divider"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageButton"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/setup_pharmacy_address" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/divider"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:background=""
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/setup_has_delivery_switch"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/divider2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/setup_save_btn"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/setup_has_delivery_switch" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**And it will look like this:**

[image]

Comment: Although there's still some difference in the vertical positions of the views, but it improved the look. using margins with constraint layout messes things up. Thank you, Tamir.

Comment: Sure, and if you want to better control your vertical positions read the link that added in my answer talking about  guidelines, once your will do it you will know how to control your view positioning in a super easy way

Answer (score 0):

It's depend upon screen size.Sometime our layout is optimial for medium or large screen size device which cause issue to small device. In order to fix this issue for smaller device too, add ScrollView as  parent layout of constraint layout

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
....
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```